# How to solve Error Blocked by Client

Tags: javascript

Im getting these error in my web page console

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: possible adblockers

Comment: check if the browser has adblocker present

Comment: Thanks it solved